# Bool array transfer from client with UDP in C

Tags: arrays, c, sockets, boolean, udp

I need to create a simple modbus application that will transfer data in bool type. I created client and server codes for this.
Client side:

```
int Client(bool message[8])
{
struct sockaddr_in si_other;
int s, slen=sizeof(si_other);
bool buf[BUFLEN];
WSADATA wsa;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 1;
}

if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 2;
}

memset((bool *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);


if (sendto(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 3;
}

//  closesocket(s);
//  WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Server side:

```
int main()
{
SOCKET s;
struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
int slen , recv_len;
bool buf[BUFLEN];
WSADATA wsa;

slen = sizeof(si_other) ;

printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Initialised.\n");

if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}
printf("Socket created.\n");

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( PORT );

if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
puts("Bind done");

while(1)
{
    printf("Waiting for data...\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    memset(buf,'0', BUFLEN);

    if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));

    for (int i=0; i<=7; i++) {
        printf("%d", buf[i]);
    }

    printf("Data: %d\n" , buf);
    printf("%s-%s-%s\n",buf[0],buf[1],buf[2]);     //When I run this code, it works just like the code with 'for' and gives an error.

    if (sendto(s, buf, recv_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

When I run the application, the data transfer is not correct. For example, when I send data as '101010', it transmits '100000'; If send data as '110101', it transmits '110000' or if  send it as '011111', it transmits '000000'. In other words, in order to read a data with a value of '1' correctly, all the values before that data must be '1'.

When I remove the 'for' part in the code and try to read the whole buf directly (   printf("Data: %d\n" , buf) ) , it reads '6421972' data. Even if I change the data, this number does not change. What can I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: Your problem is that you are calling `strlen(message)`, but `strlen()` is designed to work with NUL-terminated strings, and here `message` is an array of booleans.  I think you want to pass`8*sizeof(bool)` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not as a parameter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll quote gcc:  `warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'bool *' instead of 'bool [8]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Damn forgot about that... My bad. I blame it on being 3 am... 

Comment: So did I, at first -- I think it's a flaw in the language that it doesn't do the right/obvious thing there :(

Comment: In the server you have plenty of other problems. Like trying to print the pointer `&buf[0]` as a decimal integer. Or print `bool` values as strings. Doesn't your compiler complain?

Comment: I think you need to take a few steps back, and refresh the chapters on arrays and pointers in your text books.

Comment: I need to help again, please help me :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67718153/bool-array-transfer-from-server-with-udp-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client, strlen(message) will count chars until the first '0'encoutered. So your sent bool array *never* will be of length 8.

Your client must then take the buffer length too in parameter to fix this.

If your buffer is a true C array (not an allocated pointer) then **sizeof** statement can give the length. But if you use a malloc'd pointer for buf, sizeof statement will always return 8, never less, never more (in 64 bit systems), that is the size of a pointer only.

In short, always keep a length integer alongside with a buffer.