# Bool array transfer from server with UDP in C

Tags: arrays, sockets, server, boolean, client

I need to create a simple modbus application to transfer data from server to client in Bool type. I created client and server codes for this.
Server side:

```
int main() {
struct sockaddr_in other_addr;
SOCKET soket, slength=sizeof(other_addr);
bool message[256]={1};
WSADATA wsa;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((soket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset((bool*)&other_addr, 0, sizeof(other_addr));
other_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
other_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
other_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(server_addr);

while (1) {

    if (sendto(soket1, message, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&other_addr, slength) == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("%d\n",message);
    printf("%d-%d-%d-%d\n", message[0], message[1], message[2], message[3]);

    //closesocket(soket);
    //WSACleanup();

}
return 0;
}
```

Client side:

```
int ImportedClient()
{
SOCKET soket;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, other_addr;     
int slength=sizeof(other_addr), recv_length;      
bool message[256];                          
WSADATA wsa;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 3;
}

if((soket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == -1)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 2;
}

memset((bool *) &other_addr, 0, sizeof(other_addr));
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_addr.sin_port = htons( port );

if( bind(soket ,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr , sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 1;
}

fflush(stdout);                 
memset(message,'0', maxdata);       

if ((recv_length = recvfrom(soket, message, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &other_addr, &slength)) == -1)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 5;
}

bool x=message[0];
bool y=message[1];
bool z=message[2];
bool k=message[3];

closesocket(soket);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

When I start data transfer, 'printf ("% d \ n", message);' code gives an output '6422012'. However, when printing the elements of the message array one by one with the printf code, it prints correctly. I cannot get the correct data individually or collectively from the client side. The output of client side reads true directly. As I understand it, when trying to read from the client, it directly accepts true because 6422012 data transfers to the client. Where do I need to fix it so that it can be read correctly by the client, or how can I get it if I need to buy one by one?
Note: I've also tried sending x1, x2, x3 one by one, but again when I print them, there are 6... numbers.

Please help me :((

Answer (score 0):

According to the given code, `message` is an array.
`printf("%d", message);` will interpret the `message` *variable* as a decimal integer, says "%d". As message is an array, it is then the address of the first element of that array. "%d" will interpret this address (not the value) as an integer. So your code is printing the address in memory as a decimal number!

If you want to print the values of the array, `printf` cannot do it for you, unless...:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i ++) {
        printf("%d", message[i] ? 1 : 0); /* bool interpretation */
    }
```

That should do the trick.

Look at the following working example as a reply:
https://gist.github.com/be1/7f4976207cb8e2c7faf96b3aa3de6dd8

P.S.: don't use (bool*) cast on other_addr or server_addr since they are not of type bool.

Comment: Actually, I put the printf in the server code to read what I sent to the client. Since I import the client code into an app, I cannot directly read the data I received from the client with printf. I assign all the elements of the array I received as x1,x2,x3.. and read them one by one as true-false. However, when I run it in the app, even if I assign the whole array as '0', they all give true output in the Client. As you said, when I use printf on the server, I can read the data correctly. However, as I said, the important thing is that I need to be able to get the right data from the Client.